# Dependencies between Spark applications

Tags: apache-spark

In Apache Spark, is there some way to submit multiple applications, with some of those applications depending on the output of one/some of the other applications, so that Spark resolves the dependencies and lets apps wait on other applications that need to finish first?

Or would I have to merge everything into one big application?

Is there something available in Spark itself, or some standard library/framework on top of Spark that does this?

Comment: You should better understand and read https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement seems Controlling the spark jobs. Prefer use shell scripts or control-m or oozie or airflow or autosys or tivoli etc.. which are aimed to provide lots of flexibility for controlling the workflow.